# Scraped version of a website is different from the browser version

Tags: r, web-scraping, curl, rvest, rselenium

I would like to use R or bash scripting ("curl" on Windows) to scrap webpage.

However, the downloaded file does not contain the same information as seen on the browser. It seems that there are some hidden (at least for me) Java scripts or a like or redirection happened without changing the URL shown in the browser.

Here is an example [page](https://dip.lter-europe.net/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/f7039bcc-81bb-4cfd-85ea-28b89c7d8170). I would like, for example, to extract the link information for "B2Share Download Link" info.

Is it possible to extract such information using `rvest` or `curl`, etc?

Comment: Most modern webpages use javascript to load data after the page loads. You cannot use traditional scrapers like `rvest` or `curl` because they cannot run javascript. You can either use the developer tools in your browser to try to figure out where the data is coming from or use something like RSelenium to use a browser that can run the javascript for you.

Answer (score 2):

The website https://dip.lter-europe.net/ provides an [API](https://dip.lter-europe.net/geonetwork/doc/api/index.html) to access their data programmatically. You'll get better results that way than by scraping the website.

To get the URLs to the files in your example you can do this in R:

```
library(jsonlite)

file_urls <- 
  fromJSON("https://dip.lter-europe.net/geonetwork/srv/api/records/6208/related?type=onlines")
```

Here is an example of how to turn a search request into IDs, which we can then use to access the "Downloads and Links" for the IDs and other information.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(glue)
library(purrr)

search_url <- "https://dip.lter-europe.net/geonetwork/srv/eng/q?_content_type=json&bucket=s101&facet.q=&fast=index&from=1&resultType=details&sortBy=relevance&sortOrder=&to=20"

search_results <- fromJSON(search_url)

create_download_url <- 
  function(id) glue("https://dip.lter-europe.net/geonetwork/srv/api/records/{id}/related?type=onlines")

search_results$metadata$`geonet:info`$id |> 
  create_download_url() |> 
  map(fromJSON)
```

Comment: Thanks Till. This would be much easier for this website. However, how did you find this page ID? I mean where can I find the "6208" part of the URL in your example?

Comment: I extracted the ID from the network tab in the Firefox Inspector. You'll have to familiarize yourself with the API endpoints to find out how to get item IDs. You'll probably have to do a search request first, which will produce IDs and then feed those IDs into the `records` endpoint.

Comment: I added an example of how to get ID values from the API and process them further.